# SELECT * not working with mysql and Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i am new to Java, i am working on a simple program and i have a problem that i can not solve, i connected to mysql through jdbc and i tried to retrieve some data from the database inside a table so when i use the SQL `SELECT *` statement it doesn't work, however when I use `SELECT` and then specify some columns, it works.
here is the code:-

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class admins_records extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    public admins_records() {
        initComponents();
        con = db.mysql_connect();
        update_table();
    }

    private void update_table(){
        try{
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM admins";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            admins_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

When i use `SELECT col1, col2 ... etc` it works but when i use `SELECT *` it gives me this error :-

[image]

any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: u mean SELECT col1,col2..coln FROM tableName ??

Comment: Your `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel` method is returning a `null` reference. Check it and you'll find what's the problem

Comment: i was just modifying it while u were writing it bro lol thanks

Comment: @BackSlash can you give me more details please?

Comment: @user2869402 No, I can't. I have no informations on your class. Please post the code for the `resultSetToTableModel` method.

Comment: @BackSlash it's a built in method my friend

Comment: in addition to answer given you by user @Braj, check your stacktrace for any additional exception, and my opinion is to ditch `select * from`, as you loosing any control on ordering columns etc, so two dbs with same content can give tou different result

Comment: Watch the logs or configure your `log4j.xml` to log from `DbUtils`

Comment: @Braj how can i do that?

Comment: @user2869402 are you getting any exception if not then just copy same class in your project and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code of [DbUtils#resultSetToTableModel()](http://technojeeves.com/index.php/9-freebies/22-resultset-to-tablemodel).

Here is the some code snippet. If there is any exception then it return `null` and you can't set `null` as `TableModel`

```
public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) 
   try{
       ...
       for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
           newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
       }
       ...
   }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: create a new class with different name and copy the concept from the actual implementation and use new class in your code instead of actual one to find out the exception.